# Unexpected mapping error for MVC project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a mapping error to my application. As you can see from the code I have the

```
@RequestMapping("/productList")
```

but when I am on my homepage and hover the link Products (for /productList) on the bottom left on my browser the url is the following

```
localhost:8080/eMusiscStore/productList;jsessionid=B16DF0DE6E0089AC5F7DBE356181BBB1
```

So sometimes, the page cannot be displayed and other times the requested page (/productList) loads normally.

What can I do to be sure that my mapping will be correct every time?

I post only my HomeController. Let me know if you need another file.

```
package com.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.entities.Product;
import com.servicesapi.ProductService;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        System.out.println("HomeController home");
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/productList")
    public String getProducts(Model model) {
        System.out.println("HomeController productiList");
        List<Product> products = productService.getAllProducts();
        model.addAttribute("products", products);

        return "productList";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/productList/viewProduct/{productId}")
    public String viewProduct(@PathVariable String productId, Model model) throws IOException{

        Product product = productService.getProductById(productId);
        model.addAttribute(product);

        return "viewProduct";
    }
}
```

Comment: you can try to change getProducts() url mapping to "/productLIst/myProduct" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in the description that some time you are able to render your productList page.This could a bad cache issue.You can either try running your page incognito mode or clear cache always.Also to be double sure that the your  rest  call is working fine install postman plugin in your chrome browser and try invoking localhost:8080/eMusiscStore/productList;jsessionid=B16DF0DE6E0089AC5F7DBE356181BBB1 
If everything goes fine this should return you productList in the response body. Aren't you mentioning the type of CRUD operation?Looks like it is  a @get method.